# How can I write a controller for one-to-one relationship? I get "The ApplicationUser field is required" error in my model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two models: ApplicationUser (Identity) and Review. This models have one-to-one relationship. I scaffold a controller for Review and when I try to create an object, I get "The ApplicationUser field is required" error in my model. How should I write this controller?

Here is the code for Review model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ZaryadApp.Models
{
    public class Review
    {
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        [Required]
        public string ReviewId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser model

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ZaryadApp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual Review Review { get; set; }
    }
}
```

"Create" part of Reviews controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["ReviewId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");
    return View();
}

// POST: Reviews/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
// For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ReviewId,Text,CreatedAt")] Review review)
{
    //ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
    //var currentUserID = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    //var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == currentUserID);
    //review.ApplicationUser = user;
    //Debug.WriteLine(review.ApplicationUser.UserName);
    foreach (var modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(error.ToString());
        }
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(review);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["ReviewId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", review.ReviewId);
    return View(review);
}
```

My create view

```
<form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReviewId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ReviewId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ReviewId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Text" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CreatedAt" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CreatedAt" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CreatedAt" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

I tried to add review.ApplicationUser = currentUser but it didn't work

Comment: What's your create view look like ? Do you excute the create post action when you set the  breakpoint at the `if (ModelState.IsValid)`? What's your result of  `if (ModelState.IsValid)` ?

Comment: @QingGuo I attached my create view. ModelState.IsValid returns False

Comment: To avoid  ModelState.IsValid returns False , the first way is you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file
(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File). The second way is to add `?` to ApplicationUser , like: `public virtual ApplicationUser ?ApplicationUser { get; set; }` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so basically before the controller kicks in the framework is trying to do you a favour and get the errors. There are really 2 ways to stop this.

**1. Change the Create/View**

So when the user hits the create then pass in the application user and usually set the id (the primary key) in the form.

Normally the review class (in your case) should have something like

```
 public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

 public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Where you have the ApplicationUserId as a field in the database that links back to your ApplicationUser table.

You could create the ApplicationUser (and store in the database) on the create page then link the applictionUser and review together on the postback.

In the View you would have a hidden field for the ApplicationUserId which would be the id of your user

**2. Change the Postback**

So on the postback remove the `ModelState.IsValid`. We know it's not valid.
On the first postback, create the ApplicationUser in the database, then set the id in the review object. Using `TryValidateModel(review)` will test your `review` object and if ok, you can then save it. After that you can update the ApplicationUser with the review you have saved.